# ¿Cómo obtener el valor enviado desde los parámetros enviados por url en las clases Request de laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, validación, http

Estoy en una situación en el cual tengo que validar un parámetro enviado desde la url, por ejemplo:

> dominio.com/facultad/**10**/cursos

En el cual, me gustaría validar el parámetro 10 enviado por la URL desde clases que utiliza *Laravel* para los *Request*, validando 10 si existe en otra tabla , se que se puede realizar la validación desde el controlador realizando una consulta a la base de datos, pero debo realizarlo desde las clases *Request*.

¿Cómo puedo realizar ese proceso desde las clases *Request* que ofrece *Laravel*?

Comment: A qué te referís con "desde las clases Request"? Desde dónde querés realizar la validación? Un controlador? Un form request? Publicá tu archivo de rutas. Podes hacer algo así: `request()->route('facultad')` (si es que así se llama ese parámetro).

Answer (score 0):

creo que las clases a las que te refieres, solo sirven para validar datos que vienen de un formulario más no datos que vayan a traves de get por la url

en todo cazo puedes crear la clase con **php artisan make:request [EjemploRequest]**  sin los corchetes

una vez creado el request, lo puedes ver en la carpeta app\Http\Requests\EjemploRequest.php

veras algo como esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EjemploRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

si eres observador vas a ver que esta clase extiende de **FormRequest**

ahora para que te funcione en la función **authorize** debes colocarla como true

para usarlo en un controlador debes hacer lo siguiente

**use App\Http\Requests\EjemploRequest;**

ahora puedes hacer uso de el en una función del controlador

```
public function ejemplo(EjemploRequest $request) {

}
```

ahora en la función **rules** del formRequest dentro del return tienes acceso a los campos que envies desde el formulario quedaria de tal forma:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [
        // exists:table,column -> verifica que el campo email exista en la tabla users
        'email' => 'exists:users,email'
    ];
}
```

por lo tanto cuando una peticion sea atendida por la función ejemplo del controlador primero va a pasar por la clase y en la variable $request vienen los campos ya validados del return de la funcion **rules** de el FormRequest